# XCode "Unable to parse contraint format" on iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

Full error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint
>   format:  Expected a view  V:||     ^'
>   *** First throw call stack:

So here's the story, I am making an app for iOS 10 and 11 and everything was working well, but I decided to update Xcode to newest version (9.1 to 9.3) and now my app crashes at launch. But only on iOS11, on 10 it launches and functions pefectly

My code for setting constraints:

```
var verticalLayoutString = "V:|"

        for i in 0..<indexes.count {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: i * 20, width: 20, height: 20))
            label.text = indexes[i]
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.textColor = GlobalSettings.tint.color
            addSubview(label)
            views["label\(i)"] = label

            if i == 0 {
                verticalLayoutString += "[label\(i)]"
            }
            else {
                verticalLayoutString += "[label\(i)(==label0)]"
            }

            addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[label\(i)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterY, metrics: [:], views: views))
        }

        verticalLayoutString += "|"
```

Why is it happening?

Comment: There's an Xcode 9.3? Can't find it, even in beta.

Comment: My bad, it's 9.2, I thought I was two versions behind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexes` is empty, so the loop never runs and you wind up with a layout string of `V:||`. This isn't legal because it doesn't reference any named views, so the `|` characters can't be mapped to a view either.

Comment: Thanks, you made me realize one stupid mistake in my project, thank you!

Comment: The debugger is your friend. When code looks like it should work, but doesn't, set a breakpoint and step through your code line-by-line. Examine variables and assume everything is wrong until you can prove otherwise.